# java ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor change timing of task

Tags: java

I am in the need of changing the executing time of a runnig task for a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

i have something like

```
executor.schedule(new Runnable() {blablal},10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

during the login phase, i would like to pick up all the tasks for this user and execute them once.

it's not possible to change the execution time  of the ScheduledFuture right?

so my best option it's to do something like

```
synchronized(list) {
    Runnable a = new Runnable(){aaaa; list.remove(a)};
    executor.schedule(a,10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    list.add(a);
}
```

and at login

```
synchronize(list) {
    for (Runnable a : list) 
        a.run();
}
```

am i right?

there aren't any other better options, so i can avoid all this synchronization?

maybe a direct way to change the timeout of a ScheduledFuture

Comment: So, you just need a delayed execution of your tasks? Or do you need periodic execution of your tasks?

Answer (score 3):

Keep a handle on the `Future` that is returned when you schedule something on the [ScheduledExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html).  Instead of trying to change the execution time, you can [cancel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) the future and re-schedule it.